# MPI warning: unable to find any relevant network interfaces

Tags: mpi

I faced an issue when I run a MPI test program. I got the following warning. It seems that I can use `--mca btl_base_warn_component_unused 0` to avoid the warning. But what does it mean? Does it matter?

```
[[39141,1],0]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: kaya2

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.

NOTE: You can disable this warning by setting the MCA parameter
btl_base_warn_component_unused to 0.
```

Comment: It means no infiniband was found. If your system does not have any, then you can safely ignore this warning.